# Node versions do not match: node vs. sudo node -v ... WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As you can see in the image below, I see two different versions of node depending on which command I run.

[image: CLI]

I need the newer version, but npm sees the old version.

[image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/485329207518298123/1057604620937080862/image.png]

Many times I've removed, purged, reinstalled, etc.

I tried installing nvm as root and setting the node version there, but that didn't help either.

If I use `apt install nodejs` instead of nvm, it tells me that I already have the newest version, which it believes is `12.22.9.`

How do I get npm to recognize the newer version (`18.12.1`) of node that I installed via nvm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have a different version of the Node.js which is installed for the root and that particular user.

First, you need to uninstall Node.js:

```bash
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

or

```bash
sudo npm rm npm -g
```

If you have any problem with the above commands, then after running `which node` command, go to that directory, and run the following commands:

```bash
rm -r bin/node bin/node-waf include/node lib/node lib/pkgconfig/nodejs.pc share/man/man1/node.1
```

**Do the same thing for the current user if needed.**

The default Ubuntu/Debian package manager does not have the latest Node.js, and that's why whenever you try to install Node.js with `apt install nodejs` it says you have the latest version.

According to the [official Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions), for installing the latest version, you should follow these steps:

**Using Ubuntu**

```bash
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**P.S:** No need to run npm or node with `sudo`. Therefore, I highly recommend you to not use every command with `sudo`.

Comment: I found a fix at around the same time you posted, so I can't test your solution. However, it was in the same direction.

I used curl (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions), not nvm, to get node. Uninstalled the nvm version.  Ran into an error an used this fix: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1157#issuecomment-1131212089